# Error opening terminal: Screen

Tags: bash, terminal, root-access

I just installed nano on my Nexus 9, which is rooted.  However, when I try to run nano, it says "Error opening terminal: screen."

```
bash-3.2# nano
Error opening terminal: screen.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This would be better as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that. I'm happy to help you troubleshoot though!

Basically to answer your question it would help to have more information. How did you root your Nexus and what version of root are you using. How did you install bash and nano?What is your TERM variable set to? Are you using a terminal emulator or adb? If an emulator, which one and what is the terminal type set there? (Look in settings). If you set both of these to something nano can handle this might solve your problem.

Also Google your error message and "nano" - it seems others have had and solved similar problems.

By the way rather than responding to me it would be better if you changed your question to include information about what troubleshooting steps you took. If we solve the problem I can also edit my answer to fit the solution.